# How to connect to Directus API in localhost

Tags: php, directus

I am trying to setup directus in my website. Since my website is now at localhost I want to connect to API to get database info. I don't know where to point my endpoints in localhost.

My Ampps local server config is

```
Apache:7.1
sql:5.7.17
```

Till now I installed composer, then I tried to ping

doc example `https://example.com/server/ping`

I used `https://localhost/server/ping`

my directus is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\trial\directus-master`

what will be `https://example.com`

getting 404 error everytime.

Comment: Formatting/clarity

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate more, your question is vague with missing information.

Are you saying you have Directus setup on a server, and now you've loaded your website up locally, you want to access that remote instance?

If so, then you need to send your queries to the remote server.

**Much like:**

`https://demo-api.directus.app/server/ping`

`https://demo-api.directus.app/_/items/sales/1,2,3`

Comment: its working now,have to point my local server to public folder of directus. Thanks Shea.